Can all solutions from any possible dynamical systems be formulated as combinations of harmonic oscillators?
In my understanding, all physical oscillators are unit vectors of a Hilbert space that is represented from the group $SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$. Every dynamical system operates under this group (let's ignore relativity and view classical mechanics as a special case of quantum mechanics.) To make sure that my understanding correct, can all solutions from any possible dynamical systems be formulated as combinations of them? If yes, how? If no, why?
In general, would that apply to other groups? (I know this is no longer a physics question but a math one, but if you can answer it too then it would be neat.)

Comments to the post (v2): As a classical or a quantum system? Is dissipation allowed?

If they are physical systems, then they are allowed. So the answers to both questions are yes. I've never heard of dissipation in quantum system though
